# How to record video using Kurento in Easyrtc?

Tags: webrtc, media, kurento, easyrtc, coturn

I'm new to Webrtc and Javascript. I'm trying to build a video chat application with recording functionality on the server. Currently, I use Easyrtc as Webrtc wrapper to provide the video chat functionality and it's working great. I also setup TURN server on the cloud using Coturn and use this on Easyrtc config.

I would now like to add video recording on the server and learned that this is achieved via media server. I'm keeping an eye on Kurento for this.

I'm just confused with media server in general.

1. Can Media Server replace TURN Server?
2. If TURN and Media server are required, can Kurento be installed on the same server as Coturn?
3. Can I have Easyrtc and add Kurento for video recording? If yes, how can Kurento record the video stream from Easyrtc/Coturn? Would appreciate pseudocode if possible.
4. Am I on right track? Any other advice to consider?

Should highly appreciate your comments.

Thank you!

Comment: Any comments on this?

Comment: Anyone been succesful on integrating kurento?